# What is the most power hungry component of a air conditioner?

Tags: power-consumption

Im taking about those old school air conditioners, which draw around 1200 watts from the wall.

Comment: An AC only has one power consuming part doesnt it? The motor for the pump

Comment: @DKNguyen You seem to be forgetting about the fan, which on most units operates independently.  It *could* be done mechanically but in home units usually is not.  Granted it is not the dominant power draw, but it is a distinct one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton oh, durrrrrr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compressor motor, followed by the evaporator fan and the condenser fan (if any), then any control electronics.

Comment: Surely, the compressor.